# StackOverflowError during compilation when resolving circular generic types

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I get `StackOverflowError` when I try to compile the following code using `javac`:

```java
package test;
import test.Criteria.Builder;

public class Criteria<B extends Builder<? extends Criteria>> {
    protected Criteria(Builder builder) {
    }

    // focus this
    // if using the following code line to compile, the code will be compiled success
    // public static <B extends Builder> B builder() {
    public static <B extends Builder<E>, E extends Criteria<B>> B builder() {
        return (B) new Builder<>();
    }

    public static class Builder<C extends Criteria<? extends Builder<C>>> {
    }
}
```

I get error:

```
D:\workspace>javac Criteria.java


系统资源不足。
有关详细信息, 请参阅以下堆栈跟踪。
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.equalsIgnoreMetadata(Type.java:513)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.contains(Type.java:1150)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4769)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$Rewriter.visitTypeVar(Types.java:4724)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1681)
```

I tried to compile using the following list of JDK versions:

- oraclejdk-1.8.0_271
- oraclejdk-17.0.8
- openjdk-17.0.2
- openjdk-21.0.1

Anybody knows what's happening?

Is it something wrong with Java compiler or with my code? I want it to compile successfully.

[Bug reference java bug database; bugid:JDK-8324809](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8324809)

Comment: Hi Could you please give us - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The error is translated as: "The system resources are insufficient. For more information, see the following stack traces."

Comment: this bug has been recored to java bug database; bugid:JDK-8324809

Comment: @Akshay the code that the OP has already provided is a minimal reproducible example; what more are you expecting?

Comment: @k314159 the original code of OP wasn't MRE, I made it MRE in one of my edits

Comment: @banan3'14 you added a `main` function, but that wasn't necessary. Just compiling the class, as it was in the original post, without a `main` was sufficient to reproduce the issue. Therefore it was already an MRE. It doesn't have to be executable/runnable in order to be reproducible. The issue was with compilation only.

Comment: @k314159 I just checked and you're right, `main` isn't necessary, I just removed it. I didn't know you can compile a class without main function. If you have any more ideas how to make it more minimalistic please go ahead and edit it.

Answer (score 4):

Stack overflow error comes from the fact that compiler tries to figure out what you mean by `C extends Criteria<? extends Builder<C>>` and `B extends Builder<? extends Criteria>`. You're building an infinite diamond problem during type resolution. The compiler tries to resolve the generic type `Builder`. For that it needs all the generic type parameters, i.e. `Criteria`. For that it needs `Builder`. The recursion goes to the infinite until the stack size exceeds what the system assigns to the `javac` program and then it crashes.

Comment: i think this problem like circular dependency in spring boot

Comment: java compiler should be  tune this

Comment: has more infomation for V tables？ thank u

Comment: @rui.zhang added more explanation, if you think it's the compiler's fault you can prove it by creating a code in C

Comment: Java does not have vtables.

Comment: @user207421 what does it have instead?

Comment: It has a well-defined class file format. The error here comes during type resolution, way before code generation. You should remove all that guesswork from your answer and stick to the infinite diamond part, which is correct.

Comment: @user207421 changed v-tables to method tables, is it correct now? I left the Spring part because it's useful

Comment: No it isn’t correct. I already told you that the error precedes code generation. Nothing to do vtables or method tables whatsoever. The compiler can’t resolve the unresolvable type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256714/discussion-between-banan314-and-user207421).

Comment: No. I’ve given you all the information you need. If you think this happens during code generation please provide evidence. You were on the right track until you started to guess.